# Disable a Payment methode when a giftcard is used

Tags: shopify, payment, checkout

I have a Problem with my Shopify shop when the client uses a giftcard and uses a payment method. For most payment methods the giftcard functionally works great, but one isn't working properly. Is it possible to disable a single payment method if a customer is using a gift card to partially pay?

For most payment methods when a client is paying partially with a gift card and partially with a credit card our erp system shows 'gift_card/credit_card'.

For this one payment method, if a client is partially using a gift card and partially the payment method out erp system only shows 'gift_card'.

Comment: You should be dealing with Shopify to sort this out. This is not something SO can really help with.

Comment: @DavidLazar I'm pretty new to Shopify. Can you explain to me why it is something I have to ask Shopify about?

Comment: Simply because no one on SO can affect Payment Gateway code that is not working. Since you are new to Shopify, you will be challenged by things Shopify, so it is best you work with Shopify on those challenging things, like your Payment Gateway problem with Gift Cards.